# Spring Boot 2.x Repackage for integration tests with gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, integration-testing

i migrated our application from Spring Boot 1.5 to Spring Boot 2.2. I am struggeling with our gradle build. In the past we used the following to get an executable Jar file with all Spring dependencies to run our integration tests in our CI pipeline separately:

```
task integrationBootRepackage(type: BootRepackage, dependsOn: integrationJar) {
  enabled = true
  withJarTask = integrationJar
  customConfiguration = "integrationRuntime"
  mainClass = "io.test.IntegrationApplicationKt"
}
assemble.dependsOn integrationBootRepackage
```

The integrationJar task builds a basic jar with our integration test classes and main classes. In the past we were able to "bootify" this jar with the repackage task. But in Spring Boot 2.2, this task doesn't exist anymore. [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-jars) only tells how you can build your main JARs.

With Maven repackaging seems to be still available, as the following section is mentioned in the [Spring Maven plugin documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin//examples/repackage-classifier.html):

> You can also use the same configuration if you want to repackage a secondary artifact the same way the main artifact is replaced. The following configuration installs/deploys a single task classified artifact with the repackaged app:

Does anyone know why repackaging is still available with Maven but not with gradle? Or do i just not find the right documentation for it?

I also tried other approaches like directly inheriting our integrationJar task from `BootJar`, but it doesn't put the spring dependencies into the jar.

```
val integrationJar = tasks.register("integrationJar", BootJar::class) {
  description = "Assembles a jar archive containing the integration classes."
  group = "build"
  mainClassName = "io.test.IntegrationApplicationKt"
  archiveAppendix.set("integration")

  from(sourceSets!!["main"].output)
  from(sourceSets["integration"].output)
}
```

Can anyone provide some help on how i can achieve a Spring repackaged integrationJar file with Spring Boot 2.2 and gradle with Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the documentation of the [Spring Boot Gradle Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/). Specifically at the section [4.1. Packaging executable jars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-jars).

> Executable jars can be built using the bootJar task. The task is automatically created when the java plugin is applied and is an instance of BootJar. The assemble task is automatically configured to depend upon the bootJar task so running assemble (or build) will also run the bootJar task.

You can also do [executable wars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-wars) or [executable and deployable wars](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-and-normal).